# How can I return Optional from @Query method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to return optional from repository If @Query in Spring data JPA  is used?

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee m WHERE e.id=?1 AND e.card=?2")
Employee getById(Integer id, Card card);
```

Comment: Specify Spring Data 1 or Spring Data 2. (Note also that you can probably simply use `getByIdAndCard` and not need the `@Query`.)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it is.

you just need to change the return type of your method to `Optional<Employee>`. Your method will look like:

```java
   @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee m WHERE e.id=?1 AND e.card=?2")
   Optional<Employee> getById(Integer id, Card card);
```